# I can't see any description by my rss?

Tags: php, rss

I have this code for my rss , but when I add it to any rss reader 
like outlook for example .... I don't see description .
I saw just Title and link .

this my code :

```
<?php 


// Database settings 


include("config.php");


@header('(anti-spam-(anti-spam-(anti-spam-(anti-spam-content-type:)))) text/xml'); // Must declare the content type 
echo '<?xml version=\'1.0\' encoding=\'UTF-8\'?>'; 

$name_site="test ";

$dat = date("j/n/Y",time());

// Set RSS version. 


echo ' 
<rss version=\'2.0\'> '; 





// Start the XML. 





echo " 
<channel>"; 

echo "<title>".$name_site." RSS</title>\n";
echo "<link>".$pathsite."</link>\n";
echo "<description>test</description>\n";
echo "<date>".$dat."</date>\n";



$url=$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];


$data = mysql_query("select * FROM  `vacancies`  order by id desc limit 50"); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($data)) 
{ 




echo " 
<item> 
<title>$row[entitle]</title> 
<description>$row[entxt]</description> 
<date>$row[date]</date> 
<link>http://$url/showjob.$row[id].html</link>

</item>"; 
} 





echo ' 
</channel> 
</rss>'; 
?>
```

Any help please to show full description .

Comment: Those are some ridiculous line breaks.

Comment: You just do not see the text or is it missing in the XML returned to the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the while loop you used `$row[entitle]` in double quotes `"`.  As you didn't quote `entitle` `$row[entitle]` will become just `$row` and append by `[entitle]` as string. This will yield, `Array[entitle]` at the output.

What you have to do is use `{$row['entitle']}`. Here `{}` indicates the variable. and `'` denotes the key.

Comment: I do what you tell me about it . 
but MR.Shiplu not work ...
my rss work perfect but my problem  " full text with html elment like images , href and ..etc "  not load ... in $r['entext'] ..

Comment: @SamiloxSamilox to insert html in description tag. you need to [escape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Escaping) it or enclose by [CDATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA)

Comment: Thank you Mr.Shiplu ...
$row['entxt']=stripslashes($row['entxt']);
$row['entxt']=htmlspecialchars($row['entxt']);
<description><![CDATA[$row[entxt]]></description>

It's Ok  !